# Can not find libz.dylib when build libzip by homebrew in Mac OS 10.16 (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, cmake, dynamic-linking, libz

When building libzip by homebrew (Mac OS 10.16), it complains `` make[2]: *** No rule to make target /usr/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `lib/libzip.5.3.dylib'.  Stop. ``, but I have */usr/lib/libz.dylib* as a soft link, the real lib (libz.1.dylib) is missing.

So how could I fix this?

1. output from `brew reinstall libzip`

```
==> Installing php dependency: libzip
==> cmake .
==> make install

cd /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib && /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dzip_EXPORTS -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1 -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib  -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.16.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -o CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_winzip_aes.c.o   -c /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib/zip_winzip_aes.c
[ 85%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_winzip_aes_decode.c.o
cd /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib && /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dzip_EXPORTS -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1 -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib  -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.16.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -o CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_winzip_aes_decode.c.o   -c /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib/zip_source_winzip_aes_decode.c
[ 87%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_winzip_aes_encode.c.o
cd /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib && /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dzip_EXPORTS -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1 -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib  -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.16.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -o CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_winzip_aes_encode.c.o   -c /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib/zip_source_winzip_aes_encode.c
[ 87%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_mkstempm.c.o
cd /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib && /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dzip_EXPORTS -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1 -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib  -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.16.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -o CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_mkstempm.c.o   -c /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib/zip_mkstempm.c
[ 87%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_file_stdio_named.c.o
cd /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib && /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dzip_EXPORTS -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1 -I/tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib  -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.16.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -o CMakeFiles/zip.dir/zip_source_file_stdio_named.c.o   -c /tmp/libzip-20200703-7227-so8a0v/libzip-1.7.1/lib/zip_source_file_stdio_named.c
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `lib/libzip.5.3.dylib'.  Stop.
```

2. there are only soft links to `libz.1.dylib`  in my /usr/lib

```
~$ ls -l /usr/lib/libz.*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libz.1.1.3.dylib -> libz.1.dylib                                                                                        lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib -> libz.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib -> libz.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libz.1.2.8.dylib -> libz.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libz.dylib -> libz.1.dylib
```

3. `libz.1.dylib` is missing.

```
~$ sudo find / -name "libz.1.dylib"
/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.1.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.1.dylib

...
(lib.1.dylib from CoreSimulator)
```

Comment: You should ask the apple dev forum... beta tests fall under your NDA.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734572/709683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *Stefano Mtangoo's* comment and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710754/mac-os-10-16-linking-homebrew-installed-libraries/62734572#62734572), I fixed this by manually add cmake arguments to the fomula file.

1. Install the dependencies of libzip from homebrew.

```
brew install zlib bzip2
```

2. Add homebrew libraries to CMake definitions.

`brew edit libzip.rb`

change L22 from

```
    system "cmake", ".", *std_cmake_args
```

to

```
    system "cmake", ".", *std_cmake_args, "-DZLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.dylib","-DBZIP2_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/bzip2/lib/libbz2.a"
```

(*/usr/local/homebrew* is my homebrew prefix.)

3. Reinstall libzip.

```
brew reinstall --verbose libzip
```

notes:

You can use `brew reinstall --verbose libzip --interactive` to prevent the deletion of working directory and inspect the source.

Then use *grep* to find the broken cmake definitions and rerun *cmake ... * to test the settings.

I have tried set *PATH*/*LD_LIBRARY_PATH*, but it not works.