# CMake No rule to make target

Tags: macos, cmake, zlib

I'm trying to build [ORB_SLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) on macOS 11.4 with clang 12 and OpenCV4 and have run into this error:

`` make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `../lib/libORB_SLAM2.dylib'.  Stop. ``

This file does not exist on my Mac and I cannot add this symlink due to macOS's [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). The correct path should be `/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.dylib`

**How can I fix this `/usr/lib/libz.dylib` reference?**

[Here is my branch](https://github.com/collenjones/ORB_SLAM2/tree/fixMacOSBuild) with my macOS build changes.

I've tried to fix the problem by:

- Inspecting each of the project's direct dependencies with `otool -L` and rebuilt from source where necessary (such as OpenCV) to make sure `/usr/lib/libz.dylib` is not referenced (fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719000/can-not-find-libz-dylib-when-build-libzip-by-homebrew-in-mac-os-10-16-big-sur))
- Using CMake's `FindZLIB.cmake` module in the ORB_SLAM2 `CMakeLists.txt` to ensure the correct ZLIB is found

Below is the output showing ZLIB is found but still no luck:

```
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.11")
```

Comment: You need to find out **origin** of wrong path `/usr/lib/libz.dylib`. It could be not cleared cache (`CMakeCache.txt`), it could be some utility which gives wrong path, it could be hardcode. Unless you find the origin, you will unlikely be able to fix a problem.

Comment: It's definitely not a cache, I've cleared entire `build` directory. Do you have any tips on how I can quickly find where this path is coming from? I did a scan of `/usr/local/opt` dylibs and there are many references still to the wrong `libz` path. Hoping there is a faster way to fix this than rebuilding all of those libs from source.

Comment: I would start with the verbose build (`make VERBOSE=1`) and check out the exact command line for the linker contains the wrong path.

Comment: Searching the source and or build dir for text files containing `libz.dylib` may narrow down the search... It should occur in some file used by make as dependency...

Comment: Maybe just remove that reference and use `-lz` to link the zlib dylib already installed in macOS.

Comment: Your branch builds fine for me. Unless you're doing something explicit, you should be picking up `libz.tbd` a la `-- Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11")`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone. I was dumb and CMake was pulling in Pangolin from another project of mine. Adding Pangolin to this project solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I checked the CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake and it showed me that the Pangolin library I was using was actually one from another project of mine. Building Pangolin in this project solved the issue.