# Mac OS Big Sur 11.2 zlib missing link

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, zlib

I am using Clion with cmake and with the OS update to Big Sur there is a problem with zlib. I installed zlib via homebrew. Particularly, I get the following error

`make[3]: *** No rule to make target "/usr/lib/libz.dylib", needed by "dsle_lib_cpp".  Stop. make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dsle_lib_cpp.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dsle_lib_cpp.dir/rule] Error 2 make: *** [dsle_lib_cpp] Error 2`

Tried to solve by overwriting the system path as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734572/15456046. I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739728 without any success. I also tried to set 'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"' as suggested by homebrew. I also tried to reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools.

Any help is highly appreciated, just do not know what it could be. Thanks!

Comment: Smells like you forgot to clean the **cache** for your project after you have updated the libraries.

Comment: Tsyvarev you are my hero ;) Thanks so much! It was indeed the cache!

Comment: Note that zlib was already there before you installed it with homebrew.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Based on older posts concerning the beta version of Big Sur I thought the default zlib library was somehow corrupt.

Comment: Can you point me to these posts?

Comment: For example, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734572/15456046

Comment: Thanks. I have Big Sur, and there is no problem in the non-beta versions. (By "corrupt" they meant "missing". Somehow the link to the shared library was broken in a beta version of Big Sur.)

Answer (score 0):

Tsyvarev was absolutely right, I had to reset the cache and reload the project. Thanks so much!